# How to contain content in parallax row from overflowing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a web page where I am using a parallax effect on.

The parallax effect works but my issue is that when there is a lot of content on my row it over flows to the next row.
Below is a screenshot and link to it, [image]

```
http://skyechopencil.com/retreat-newest/
```

Please check image 1 - 7 you will see it over flows to the next line and does not look good, I want it to stay in its row until its scrolled too.

This is what I have tried as a class, I have tried to bring it to back, but I guess its not the right solution it got stuck

```
.imr{
    z-index : 1;
    position : absolute;
}
```

Comment: there are seven images when u get to the row on that page sir and they overflow unto the next row, please have a look

Comment: Not sure what you want, do you want all images in the same row or? please clarify your question

Comment: yes, i want them to stay within their row, the parallax effect on that row causes the issue, hw can i over come that sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this as a class and assign it to your row, works for me

```
.myclass{
no-repeat fixed center top / cover;
    padding: 50px 0;
    height: 510px;
    margin: 25px -40px 0 -40px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```